# R - Need help on Multi-State Markov

Tags: r

[image]

[image]

The above picture is my code, everything is normal, but I get the warning of the following picture.

I would like to ask why it is caused? And what should I do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).  Also, you maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a *minimal reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.